# How to extract dynamic number in header tag in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

here is the html. I want to extract 1814400752 in h2 tag. 
I have tried using xpath but it extracts just  "Order number:" without number. Please advise.

`<h2 _ngcontent-c57="">
    <pwwgen-label _ngcontent-c57="" default="Order number:" name="e-comm-confirmation-order-number" _nghost-c8="" ng-reflect-name="e-comm-confirmation-order-numb" ng-reflect-default="Order number:">
        <span _ngcontent-c8="">Order number:
        </span>
    </pwwgen-label>
1814400752</h2>`

Comment: Can you share me the tried XPath?

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the parent tag from the child xpath

Below XPath can be used

**Xpath:** `//*[name='e-comm-confirmation-order-number']/parent::h2`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name='e-comm-confirmation-order-number']/parent::h2")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the text **1814400752** is a child node of `<h2>` tag. To extract the text **1814400752** you can use the following solution *(Java)*:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//h2[@_ngcontent-c57]"));
String myText = ((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", myElement).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It was taking time to render the number on the page, so it could not extract it immediately after executing below code. I have to use some sync and then execute and it worked. Thanks for all your responses.

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//h2[@_ngcontent-c57]"));
String output = element.getAttribute("innerText");
```